# How to resize background image in PaintDC in wxPython?

Tags: python, wxpython

I have a simple wxPython app showing a screenshot in fullscreen. The screenshot resolution matches the actual resolution of the monitor, however after changing the scaling setting in Windows the image is being displayed too large and doesn't fit the screen anymore. How can I change the scale of the image back to original?

```
class Window(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, image: PIL.Image):
        wx.Frame.__init__(self, None, wx.ID_ANY, "app_name")

        width, height = image.size
        image = wx.Image(width=width, height=height, data=image.tobytes())
        self.image = image.ConvertToBitmap()

        self.Bind(wx.EVT_PAINT, self._on_paint)
        self.ShowFullScreen(True)

    def _on_paint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        brush = wx.Brush(self.image)
        dc.SetBackground(brush)
        dc.Clear()
```

I have tried `image.Rescale(*wx.GetDisplaySize())`, which works to bring the image back to original size, but it looks low resolution.

Comment: I've also tried `dc.SetLogicalScale(0.8, 0.8)`, but it has the same problem with the image becoming low resolution

Comment: There isn't enough code to reproduce the issue. Your current example is missing the necessary imports (`import wx`, `import PIL`), no driver code (`app = wx.App()`, `window = Window(img)`, `app.MainLoop()`), and I completely cannot get what your problem is, there is absolutely no code that actually does anything, I tested your code and all I get is a still image with no interactivity (I even had to use Alt+F4 to close it). Please add enough code to clearly demonstrate the problem so that I can help you.

Comment: Let me a stupid question as a Linux user: you mean you changed the window size or the settings for the screen on the OS Windows? I assume the second but can't see the influence on the problem.

Answer (score -1):

`wx.ScreenDC().GetPPI()` would work for you,

```py
    def _on_paint(self, event):
        dc = wx.PaintDC(self)
        screen_dc = wx.ScreenDC()
        dpi_scale_factor = screen_dc.GetPPI()[0] / 96.0

        image_width, image_height = self.image.size
        display_width, display_height = self.GetSize()

        scaled_width = int(image_width * dpi_scale_factor)
        scaled_height = int(image_height * dpi_scale_factor)

        # Scale the image using high-quality resampling
        scaled_image = self.image.resize((scaled_width, scaled_height), resample=PIL.Image.LANCZOS)

        # Calculate the position to centre the scaled image on the screen
        x = (display_width - scaled_width) // 2
        y = (display_height - scaled_height) // 2

        dc.DrawBitmap(scaled_image.ConvertToBitmap(), x, y)
```

In this code, the GetPPI() method is used to retrieve the current DPI of the screen. By calculating the scaling factor based on the ratio of the screen's DPI to the standard 96 DPI, you can ensure that the image is displayed in its original resolution regardless of the scaling settings in Windows. The resize method is used to scale the image while maintaining its quality, and the DrawBitmap method is used to draw the scaled image on the screen.